# How to post, put and delete data in Wagtail by using v2 API?

Tags: wagtail

I have used API v2. By using this I can only fetch the data. I am not able to post data in Wagtail.

Comment: Just curious, what does your set up look like? are you providing a separate editor to users where they can add / edit pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't - [as per the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#wagtail-api-v2-usage-guide), the v2 API is read-only.